# Electric oven keeps cutting out

Tags: oven

My electric oven keeps cutting out (completely shutting down, all lights, fan and heating element turn off). After a few minutes it starts up again. This happens repeatedly.

The oven has a mechanical analogue timer. Fiddling with the timer in a specific way causes the oven to start up again, but a minute later it shuts down, continuing the cycle.

I have now opened up the oven and removed the whole timer, but the problem persists!! At this stage we are about ready to just get rid of the oven and get a new one, but I wanted to know if it’s possible that this would a be a problem with the wiring in the property rather than the oven itself?

The oven is a Baumatic BOR610BL electric integrated oven.

Comment: What does the troubleshooting section of the owner's manual say about it?

Comment: Stop doing that. You are angering the gremlins inside your walls, and they may decide to set your house on fire if you continue.

Answer (score 2):

### It's a bad electrical connection that is failing thermally.

It works when it's cold, but when you put a load on it, it heats up. That makes materials expand and that causes a loss of connection.  **Because the connection is terminated improperly**.  Something like

- Screws not properly torqued, causing too little pressure for it to accommodate temperature changes
- Screws torqued too hard, meaning normal warming is deforming (flowing) the metal
- Differences in expansion rate of aluminum vs copper, because the terminals are not designed to accommodate this with aluminum.

So every connection needs to be opened up, inspected, cleaned and re-done with proper screw torques, aluminum anti-oxidant, and with legal connections.  For instance a copper-only receptacle may need copper pigtails, with an Al-Cu splice being made with MAC Block Connectors.

It may not only be disconnecting.  It may also be doing **series arcing** before it fails altogether.  That makes a lot of heat and can start a fire.

Comment: Might be a properly functioning overheat switch, with a problem causing it to overheat - or a malfunctioning overheat switch.

Answer (score 0):

From their troubleshooting guide:

**Won't switch on**

Oven is set on 'auto' function
If your oven shows the word 'auto' or the letter 'A' then it is in the automatic mode and will not start, and the internal light will not come on. It will need to be set into the manual operation mode.

Look for the button with a hand symbol, press and release this and then use the '+' or '-' keys to adjust the time of day. Once you have set the clock to display the time of day release the buttons and the display should show the cook pot symbol. The oven is now ready to start cooking.